# Does progress from Supply Raid carry over to Survivors (and vice versa) in The Last of Us multiplayer?

Tags: the-last-of-us

For example, if I'm on Week 7 in one mode, do I continue from that point in the other mode or does it start from scratch?

I'm getting attacked and I don't want to risk not meeting the challenge by making it harder on myself and switching to Survivors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it carries over. Your progress in the meta game is consistent no matter which game mode you play - you'll notice that your meta game progress (your week, day and challenge, if applicable) is visible from the first multiplayer menu, before you choose a game type.